# tkinter optionmenu not working

Tags: python, tkinter

Working with Tkinter, and I'm having some trouble getting the OptionMenu to work properly. 
I'm creating a new window inside a function, with an OptionMenu and a label. Simple enough. 
But, it seems that I can't select an option from the OptionMenu. If I put it outside the function, it works fine. But, I need to be able to create the window on a function call.

Here's the function:

```
def ask_a_question():
    question = Tk()
    question.geometry('300x100')
    qs = ['test0', 'test1', 'test2']
    q = StringVar()
    q.set(None)
    Label(question, text = "placeholder").grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10)
    questions = OptionMenu(question, q, *qs)
    questions.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10)
    question.mainloop()
```

The code above executes as a command on a button.

In the window that it creates, I can see all the widgets, but selecting any of the options in the OptionMenu does not update it. I had a similar problem with button images when creating a window in the main code and creating a button in a function. 
Does tkinter not play well with functions? Or is there a trick to get it to work properly?

Comment: This is because to create a new window you need to use `Toplevel`, not `Tk`. A program should only have a single call to `Tk`.

Comment: I think you should use classes as your `question` windows that inherit from `Toplevel` widget. Then use a function just to instantiate an object of that class.

Comment: to create second window use `question = Toplevel()` and don't use second `mainloop()` because it makes problem with values in `StringVar`.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll give this a shot soon, but this seems to be a concise answer.

Answer (score 1):

Summing up what was said in the comments:

- Never use several `Tk` instances, use `Toplevel` widgets instead.
- Call `mainloop` only once, on the root window (i.e. the only  `Tk` instance).

So by replacing `Tk` by `Toplevel` in the function should solve your problem. Here is the corresponding code:

```
import tkinter as tk

def ask_a_question():
    question = tk.Toplevel(root)
    question.geometry('300x100')
    qs = ['test0', 'test1', 'test2']
    q = tk.StringVar(question, 'None') 
    tk.Label(question, text = "placeholder").grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
    questions = tk.OptionMenu(question, q, *qs)
    questions.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

root = tk.Tk()

tk.Button(root, text='Question', command=ask_a_question).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

By the way, you can directly pass the initial value of the `StringVar` as a second argument: `tk.StingVar(master, initial_value)`.

If you want the main window to be frozen as long as the toplevel containing the question is opened, you can add `question.grab_set()` in `ask_a_question`.

Comment: Any advantage to importing tkinter as tk? Or is that just for clarity?

Comment: @user3477099 When you do `from tkinter import *`, you crowd the namespace with a lot of things and sometimes it can lead to issues. For instance if you define a class / function / variable with the same name as a tkinter one, there can be name clashes.